# Как хранить файлы в Laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, файлы, файловая-система

Допустим у меня есть приложение на laravel и есть админ-часть которая позволяет создавать мне посты с музыкальными аудиозаписями, которые выводятся на странице постов, как и куда мне сохранять эти аудиозаписи. И плюс я же это все на хостинг хочу выложить.

Comment: [Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem), или, как вариант - внешнее хранилище (аля gdrive) и записывать ссылку в бд, к примеру.

Comment: @InDevXПочему `или`? Можно же использовать адаптер для `gdrive`, `s3`, `webdav` и т.д. При этом разницы никакой не почувствуешь (ну разве что в скорости сохранения)

Comment: @IvanDudarev потому что каждый для себя решает что где и как хранить, и не во всех случаях можно, и нужно так делать.

Comment: спасибо за информацию)